# UBUNTU 14.04 works slow and stalls often

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot

The Following are Basics of My System

MEMORY: 991.0 MiB

OROCESSOR: Pentium(R) Dual-Core CPU E5200 @ 2.50GHz × 2

GRAPHICS: Intel® G33 x86/MMX/SSE2

OS Type: 32-bit

DISK: 116.5 GB

I have set up UBUNTU 14.04, parallel to WIN 7, which has a Disk space of 40 GB

MY PROBLEMS:

1. Booting is a bit slow - often stretching to 3 min
2. All Applications take about 1 min time to open
3. Firefox often stalls (even the latest version, always updated automatically)
4. Most Applications get faded and it takes more than a min to come back to "life". Till then nothing could be operated
5. How do I CLEAN Disk?

Thanks for help

Hariharan

Answer (score 0):

Sorry mate, but since you have low-hardware system, I would suggest you to use Xubuntu or Lubuntu. The new Ubuntu unity 14.04 is definitely slow on older machines. Even I feel it slow on my 2GB, Core-i3 system. 
So better try [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/) or even more lightweight [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/). 
Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for your support and help. The question is: When i set up Xubuntu, would i loose all my Ubuntu 14.04 data? How do I protect those data?  Thanks

Comment: That depends on whether you have made a separate partition for your _home_ folder in Ubuntu or not. If yes, then while installing Xubuntu, just choose `something else` and DO NOT format your _home_ partition, just label it as _`home`_.

Comment: I dont have a separate additional partition made.